# Convert mySQL query to KNEX

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am converting series of queries to Knex syntax.
I am having problem with this query:

```
SELECT id,reviewed,log_reference,CONVERT(notification USING utf8),create_time,update_time,store,user_id
FROM store_failure_log
WHERE reviewed = 0
AND create_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR AND NOW();
```

More precisely this line:

```
SELECT id,reviewed,log_reference,CONVERT(notification USING utf8),create_time,update_time,store,user_id
```

I have this Knex in place:

```
knex('store_failure_log')
        .select('id', 'reviewed', 'log_reference', 'CONVERT(notification USING utf8)', 'create_time', 'update_time', 'store', 'user_id').convert('notification USING utf8')
        .where('reviewed', 0)
        .where(knex.raw('create_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR AND NOW()'))
```

that produces this sql query:

```
select `id`, `reviewed`, `log_reference`, `CONVERT(notification USING utf8)`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `store`, `user_id` from `store_failure_log` where `reviewed` = 0 and create_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR AND NOW()
```

Problem is in the: Convert(notification USING utf8).

The query is not valid, since the Convert is in parentheses. How can I write it with the knex?

In general how do I include SQL function calls in the KNEX syntax?

Comment: Not a direct answer but how about specify UTF8 in your connection string then skip `CONVERT` in your query?

Comment: That is possible resolution. But I would like to get a better grasp of Knex, and especially how to use SQL function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [raw](https://knexjs.org/#Raw) to include SQL function calls in your Knex query, like you've already done in your `where`:

```
knex('store_failure_log')
        .select(knex.raw('id, reviewed, log_reference, CONVERT(notification USING utf8), create_time, update_time, store, user_id'))
        .where('reviewed', 0)
        .where(knex.raw('create_time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR AND NOW()'))
```

Comment: Your `.select(knex.raw('id', 'reviewed', 'log_reference', 'CONVERT(notification USING utf8)', 'create_time', 'update_time', 'store', 'user_id'))` syntax is wrong and will throw an error.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected it by removing the unnecessary quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed version of @Veve's answer with correct quoting of identifiers and knex.raw syntax:

```
knex('store_failure_log')
        .select('id', 'reviewed', 'log_reference', knex.raw('CONVERT(?? USING utf8)', ['notification']), 'create_time', 'update_time', 'store', 'user_id')
        .where('reviewed', 0)
        .where(knex.raw('?? BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 18 HOUR AND NOW()', ['create_time']))
```

https://runkit.com/embed/lh2i1qif7obx